Ошибка при сортировке выборкой по min в списке. Происходит, если встречаются дубликаты чисел-элементов
def sorting(spisok):
    for i in range(len(spisok)): 
        mn=spisok.index(min(spisok[i:]))
        spisok[i],spisok[mn]=spisok[mn],spisok[i]
liste=[5, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6]
sorting(liste)

По максимуму уже реализовывал. По минимуму оказалось сложнее.
При i=5 минимум должен найтись в диапазоне [spisok[5]:], но программа упорно присваивает имени mn - цифру spisok[5], в результате чего на индекс 4 ставится 8, а на 5й индекс - 5, дальше программа работает правильно.

Опять таки странно, что минимальным для программы становится максимальная цифра - 8)


Я думаю, что проблема всё-таки связана с изменениями в списке и компилятор что - то путает в процессе из-за моего кода. Подумывал о вводе копии стартовой версии списка  и введение условия на проверку .count() каждого элемента, но во-первых это какие-то костыли, а во-вторых понял, что от этого всё только запутается.
Очень хочется понять, что надо изменить в коде, чтоб работало без костылей.
P.S.
Финальный результат сортировки:


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.. 2. как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

spisok.index(min(spisok[i:])) -> spisok.index(min(spisok[i:]), start=i).

Этот вопрос похож на: Python. Если в списке есть одинаковые числа, то не могу сортировать через min. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how
